# TLP and graphics card performance

Tags: debian, power-management, amd-graphics

I have a laptop with two graphics cards: an integrated Intel, and an RX 550. When I enable TLP for power-management, the performance of the RX 550 is cut in half, making it even worse than the integrated intel one. This is regardless of the power state being AC or battery.

The card is blacklisted in `/etc/default/tlp` by the two following settings:

- The default `RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="amdgpu nouveau nvidia radeon"` (the card is using the amdgpu module).
- and `RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST="02:00.0"` where `02:00.0` is the PCI slot of the card accoring to `lspci`.

However, as I said there still seems to be a considerable power-management performance hit.

How can I disable power-management for the dGPU card when on AC?